# qemu based Android emulator, architecture x86 with Intel Haxm: Permission denied for system.img

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, emulation, haxm

Does anyone know how to fix the below error? I get it when trying to start an qemu based Android emulator in Visual Studio with an x86 CPU/ADI.

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'newAndroid86'
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
qemu-system-x86_64.exe: -drive if=none,index=0,id=system,file=C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1/system-images\android-23\default\x86_64\/system.img: could not open disk image C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1/system-images\android-23\default\x86_64\/system.img: Could not open 'C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1/system-images\android-23\default\x86_64\/system.img': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that one of those folders are NOT read-only. Go to My Computer and get the properties of C:\ and see if there is a black square in the Read-Only radio box.

Comment: It is sufficient to check the path     C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1/system-images\